# How do I remove multiple exceptions?

Tags: laravel, laravel-7

I want to handle exceptions in my project and send myself messages if an error occurs. I added several classes from which I do not want to receive errors when they occur in Handler.php, but this does not work, I continue to receive errors related to authentication (the user visits the site page, he is redirected to the login page and I receive an exception message)

I will be glad for any help

my Handler.php

```
class Handler extends ExceptionHandler
{

    protected $dontReport = [
        //
        \Illuminate\Auth\AuthenticationException::class,
        \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
        \Illuminate\Auth\Access\AuthorizationException::class,
        \Illuminate\Validation\ValidationException::class,
    ];


    protected function context()
    {
        try {
            return array_merge(parent::context(), [
                'url' => Request::fullUrl(),
                'input' => Request::except(['password', 'password_confirmation']),
                'userId' => Auth::id(),
                'email' => Auth::user() ? Auth::user()->email : null,
                'server_name' => $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'],
            ]);

        } catch (Throwable $e) {
            return [];
        }
    }

    protected $dontFlash = [
        'password',
        'password_confirmation',
    ];


    public function report(Exception $exception)
    {



        $array = array("message" => "Ошибка: ".$message, "alias" => $aliasHash, "description" => $description, "source" => $source,
                        "details" => array("userId" => $user, "email" => $email, "url" => $source, "input" => $output));


        $curl = curl_init();
        $inc = json_encode($array);

        curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
            CURLOPT_URL => "https://api.eu.opsgenie.com/v2/alerts",
            CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
            CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
            CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
            CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
            CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
            CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
            CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "POST",
            CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $inc,
            CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
                "Authorization: GenieKey 123",
                "Content-Type: application/json"
            ),
        ));

        $response = curl_exec($curl);

        curl_close($curl);

        parent::report($exception);
    }
    
    public function render($request, Exception $exception)
    {
        return parent::render($request, $exception);
    }
}
```

Comment: `\Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authenticate::class` is not an exception btw

Comment: @lagbox thanks, added to check, but the AuthenticationException class is present in the list, but errors still come

Comment: right but your `report` method is running before `parent::report` so you are deaiing with all the exceptions regardless of that list ... that `parent::report` method is where the exception is checked to see if it should be reported or not, which is something you are not doing

Comment: @lagbox exactly, thank you very much, my carelessness